# Rooting HTC One M7 Verizon

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, htc-one

I have an unrooted HTC One M7, from Verizon. I used to be able to root it with KingoRoot, but now that does not work. I have tried many things to do this:

- KingRoot
- KingoRoot
- TowelRoot
- WeakSauce
- The PC Version for KingoRoot
- iRoot (PC and app)
- And several other programs

None of those worked. I am running 5.0.2
I can not unlock my bootloader with HTCDev.com because my phone is branded by Verizon.

Also, Rumrunner does not work. I get either: (F**k it) or (Such dumb issues you have...). I would also like to know what is causing this.

My end goal is to be root with Cyanogenmod and TWRP Touch.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I think it would be good if I provide some more information:

The HTC Sense version is 6.0

The Software number is 6.22.605.6

The HTC SDK API level is 6.55

The PRI Version is 4.79_002

The PRL version is 15480

The ERI Version is 5

The Kernel version is:

```
3.4.10-gdcab6f5
and@AABM #1
SMP PREEMPT
```

The Baseband Version is 1.13.41.1209

The Build number is 6.22.605.6 CL495599 release-keys

And the Software status is Official

I think some of these aren't relevant, but I just put everything to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

http://theroot.ninja/

Support almost all HTC devices, starting with HTC M7 up to HTC 10 and also Motorola's.

The only chance that you have is the Sunshine root app. But this is a paid method, and there is not free version.
It will check if the device is supported and if root is available and then ask you to pay using Paypal (that was the last method when i used it awhile ago).

Comment: I do not have $25 to do this. I have tried that before. And Sunshine needs root to do the S-OFF.

Comment: Sunshine can also get root before doing it all those things. And yes, its $25.

Comment: Will it charge you even it doesnt work?

Comment: As i said, it first verifies if it can work, and if yes, it aks to pay. If not, it lets you know it does not.